# Could not find main class Spring-Boot application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am not able to run my Spring-Boot Framework application in intellij. I am using maven and for some reason it does not find my main class. Also in my Spring application class I get an error for SpringApplication.run that says Cannot access org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>SeleniumPoker</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--Utility -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--  JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>ca.carleton.poker.PokerApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    <descriptorRef>code</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>${pom.artifactId}</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<groupId>SeleniumPoker</groupId>
```

Here is my StarterClass:

```
package ca.carleton.poker;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

import ca.carleton.poker.game.PokerSocketHandler;

/**
 * Main class - launch the application and register endpoint handlers.
 *
 * 
  */
@SuppressWarnings("SpringFacetCodeInspection")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebSocket
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ca.carleton.poker")
public class PokerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
implements WebSocketConfigurer {

@Autowired
private PokerSocketHandler PokerSocketHandler;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PokerApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(final WebSocketHandlerRegistry 
webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
    webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(this.PokerSocketHandler, "/game")
            .withSockJS();
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder) {
    return springApplicationBuilder.sources(PokerApplication.class);
}
```

}

Comment: do you need to use this specific version? maybe you can try the newest and see if that works: 2.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: So, how do you run it from Idea? What is your run configuration in other words? Also, have you tried to execute it from terminal by simply using `mvn spring-boot:run`?

Comment: You clearly are packaging this as a WAR, but you have no `<package>` element in your POM file. So start by including that to be clear to Maven your intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like version mismatch with spring core libraries and springboot version, try with compatible version, still if you see issue, remove .m2 folder completely and run again and see, good luck.

Comment: How do I know what versions are compatible?